# How can I call a function from different buttons?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am trying to put different buttons with same function in switch statement. Every button needs to call same function but with different switch parameter.

```
    <button type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" class="dugme1" id="btnSQRT">
    SQRT    
    </button>
    <button type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" class="dugme1" id="btnSIN" style="margin-left: 
     100px;">
    SIN
    </button>
    <button type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" class="dugme1" id="btnCOS" style="margin-left: 
     100px;">
    COS
    </button>
    <button type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" class="dugme1" id="btnROUND" style="margin-left: 
    100px;">
    ROUND
    </button>
```

And here is JS code,

```
    <script>
    function myFunction(){
    var x = prompt("Input number beteen 1 i 999");
    if(x > 0 && x < 1000){
    switch(x){
        case 0:
            document.getElementById("btnSQRT");
            document.write("nesta");
            break;
            case 1:
                document.getElementById("btnSIN");
                document.write("nesta");
                break;
                case 2:
                    document.getElementById("btnCOS");
                    document.write("nesta");
                    break;
                    case 3:
                        document.getElementById("btnROUND");
                        document.write("nesta");
                        break;
      }
      }
       else{
       alert("Thats not a wanted number");
      }
      }
      </script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with those switch statements?

Answer (score 0):

Change all of your `onclick="myFunction()"` to `onclick="myFunction(this)"` - that will allow you to test for the switch in `myFunction` - in which case you want to switch on the button ID rather than the prompt value.

```
function myFunction(el){ // el will be the button that called the function
    var x = prompt("Input number between 1 i 999");
    if(x > 0 && x < 1000){
    switch(el.id){ // switching on the ID of the button which tells us which math to use
        case 'btnSQRT':
            alert('The square root is ' + Math.sqrt(x));
            break;

         .....
```

I am not sure what 'nesta' and document.write was for, so I removed them here.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to switch between INT numbers, and "prompt" return a STRING. So, It will never get in any switch statement. To solve this, I just added a "parseInt()" in your prompt variable.

I changed "document.write('nesta')" by inner.HTML('nesta'), so, it changes the text in the button. But, to change the text inside the button, you got to set a variable to each button.

**HTML:**

```
<button type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" class="dugme1" id="btnSQRT">SQRT</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" class="dugme1" id="btnSIN" style="margin-left: 100px;">SIN</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" class="dugme1" id="btnCOS" style="margin-left: 100px;">COS</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" class="dugme1" id="btnROUND" style="margin-left: 100px;">ROUND</button>
```

**JS:**

```
function myFunction(){
    var x = prompt("Input number beteen 1 i 999");
    var x = parseInt(x);

    if(x > 0 && x < 1000) {
        switch(x){
            case 1:
                var nesta = document.getElementById("btnSQRT");
                nesta.innerHTML = 'nesta';
                break;
            case 2:
                var nesta =document.getElementById("btnSIN");
                nesta.innerHTML = 'nesta';
                break;
            case 3:                    
                var nesta = document.getElementById("btnCOS");
                nesta.innerHTML = 'nesta';
                break;
            case 4:
                var nesta =document.getElementById("btnROUND");
                nesta.innerHTML = 'nesta';
                break;
        }
    } else {
        alert("Thats not a wanted number");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have:

1. One event listener for all buttons.
2. getting the "value" from the button using the attribute `id`. An alternative could be to use a data-attribute (like I did with the 2ed button).
3. A `switch` statement for handling what to do next.

It is not completely clear for me if the `switch` statement is the right approach here. Please comment if you have questions.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  let buttons = document.getElementById('buttons');
  let output = document.getElementById('output');
  
  buttons.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.nodeName == 'BUTTON') {
      switch (e.target.id) {
        case 'btnSQRT':
          output.innerHTML = 'You clicked SQRT';
          break;
        case 'btnSIN':
          output.innerHTML = 'You clicked SIN';
          break;
        case 'btnCOS':
          output.innerHTML = 'You clicked COS';
          break;
        case 'btnROUND':
          output.innerHTML = 'You clicked ROUND';
          break;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div#buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <button id="btnSQRT">SQRT</button>
  <button data-func="SIN" id="btnSIN">SIN</button>
  <button id="btnCOS">COS</button>
  <button id="btnROUND">ROUND</button>
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```